# how to retrive php array value to android

Tags: php, android, arrays

I am having remote database and php file(ie) this php page will access that db and it fetch the data from the db and that value was stored in array[]  , here I have to retrieve that array values to ma android program and I have to store those value in string value .
My table name is aaa, that table have id,firstvalue,secondvalue.

Php coding::

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aaa
WHERE id='$id'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "value1:".$row['firstvalue'] ."              |        ". "value2 " . $row['secondvalue'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

Here I have to get that row['firstvalue'] and $row['secondvalue'] and store these two array value into my android program, help me for this , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the array and pass the variable to the java file.

Comment: I am new to Serialize  and php as well as android, can u please explain it

Comment: first fill the array with all the values you need, then use the  [json_encode() function](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

On your php File you will have to get the variables and set them in an array

Try this

```
$response = array();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aaa WHERE id='$id'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $response["value1"] = $row['firstvalue'] ;
      $response["value2"] = $row['secondvalue'] ;  
    }

echo json_encode($response);
```

Don't use any echo on this php page!

On your App you will have to use JSon, but since you dind't post any code for you App is quite hard to help you out on that end.

But a good example for the thing you are trying to do can be found here.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/